# Snake class for simple Snake clone

Tags: c++, object-oriented, game, sfml, snake-game

NOTE: I'm only including the snake class (only one file) here because the rest of the code doesn't need reviewing. If you need to see the complete code for whatever reason, it is available on GitHub [here](https://github.com/Orfby/SFML-Snake-Clone/tree/master/src) (unless I delete it).

I decided, since I never seem to finish my own original projects, that I would create a Snake clone using SFML and C++. I only created a `Snake` class, because it handles almost everything to do with the game, like the board, apples and the snake itself. The class doesn't entirely rely on SFML, because it only needs it for drawing and for the `Vector2` struct/class

Snake.hpp

```
#ifndef SNAKE_HPP
#define SNAKE_HPP

//Standard C++:
#include <array>
#include <vector>
//SFML Headers:
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

//Enumerator for all four directions:
enum direction {up, down, right, left, none};

class Snake
{
    private:
        //2D Array for displaying board:
        std::array<std::array<int, 40>, 40> board;
        //Direction the snake is moving:
        direction snakeDirection;
        //Location of apple:
        sf::Vector2f appleLocation;

        //So the snake doesn't move slower/faster depending on the framerate:
        sf::Clock snakeMoveClock;
        //Vector of each pixel of snake body parts:
        std::vector<sf::Vector2f> snakeBodyPartLocations;

    public:
        //Function so the player can change it's direction:
        void changeDirection(direction newSnakeDirection)
        {
            //If statement so the user doesn't kill themself by moving backwards:
            if (((snakeDirection == up)   && (newSnakeDirection != down))  || ((snakeDirection == down) && (newSnakeDirection != up)) ||
                ((snakeDirection == left) && (newSnakeDirection != right)) || ((snakeDirection == right) && (newSnakeDirection != left)))
            {
                snakeDirection = newSnakeDirection;
            }
            //Unless the snake is only one pixel:
            else if (snakeBodyPartLocations.size() == 1)
            {
                snakeDirection = newSnakeDirection;
            }
        }

        void update()
        {
            sf::Time elapsedTime = snakeMoveClock.getElapsedTime();
            //Update every 150ms:
            if (elapsedTime.asMilliseconds() >= 150)
            {
                //Go through every body part and move:
                for (int i = signed(snakeBodyPartLocations.size() - 1); i >= 0; --i)
                {
                    //If it's the snake's head:
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        sf::Vector2f snakeHeadLocation = snakeBodyPartLocations.at(0);
                        if (snakeDirection == up) {snakeHeadLocation.y = snakeHeadLocation.y - 1;}
                        else if (snakeDirection == right) {snakeHeadLocation.x = snakeHeadLocation.x + 1;}
                        else if (snakeDirection == down) {snakeHeadLocation.y = snakeHeadLocation.y + 1;}
                        else if (snakeDirection == left) {snakeHeadLocation.x = snakeHeadLocation.x - 1;}

                        snakeBodyPartLocations.at(0) = snakeHeadLocation;

                    }
                    //Else:
                    else
                    {
                        snakeBodyPartLocations.at(i) = snakeBodyPartLocations.at(i - 1);
                    }
                }

                //If the snake's head hit the apple:
                if ((appleLocation.x == snakeBodyPartLocations.at(0).x) && (appleLocation.y == snakeBodyPartLocations.at(0).y))
                {
                    //Generate a new apple:
                    while (true) //While statement untill a apple isn't inside the snake's body
                    {
                        int randomAppleX = rand() % 38 + 1;
                        int randomAppleY = rand() % 38 + 1;
                        if (board.at(randomAppleY).at(randomAppleX) == 0)
                        {
                            board.at(randomAppleY).at(randomAppleX) = 2;
                            appleLocation = sf::Vector2f(randomAppleX, randomAppleY);
                            break; //Break because it isn't in the snake's body
                        }
                    }

                    //Grow the Snake:
                    //If the snake is one pixel, create a new body part
                    //in the direction opposite to where it's moving:
                    if (snakeBodyPartLocations.size() == 1)
                    {
                        sf::Vector2f tailLocation = snakeBodyPartLocations.back();
                        if (snakeDirection == up) {tailLocation.y = tailLocation.y + 1;}
                        else if (snakeDirection == down) {tailLocation.y = tailLocation.y - 1;}
                        else if (snakeDirection == right) {tailLocation.x = tailLocation.x + 1;}
                        else if (snakeDirection == left) {tailLocation.x = tailLocation.x - 1;}
                        snakeBodyPartLocations.push_back(tailLocation);
                    }
                    //If the snake is larger than one pixel, create a body part
                    //that follows the pattern the snake is moving in:
                    else
                    {
                        sf::Vector2f tailLocation = snakeBodyPartLocations.back();
                        if (snakeBodyPartLocations.at(snakeBodyPartLocations.size() - 2).x == tailLocation.x + 1) {tailLocation.x = tailLocation.x - 1;}
                        else if (snakeBodyPartLocations.at(snakeBodyPartLocations.size() - 2).x == tailLocation.x - 1) {tailLocation.x = tailLocation.x + 1;}
                        else if (snakeBodyPartLocations.at(snakeBodyPartLocations.size() - 2).y == tailLocation.y + 1) {tailLocation.y = tailLocation.y - 1;}
                        else if (snakeBodyPartLocations.at(snakeBodyPartLocations.size() - 2).y == tailLocation.y - 1) {tailLocation.y = tailLocation.y + 1;}
                        snakeBodyPartLocations.push_back(tailLocation);
                    }
                }

                //Check if the snake has collided with something:
                for (int i = signed(snakeBodyPartLocations.size() - 1); i >= 0; --i)
                {
                    //If any of the body parts collide with the border:
                    if ((snakeBodyPartLocations.at(i).x < 1) || (snakeBodyPartLocations.at(i).x > 38) ||
                        (snakeBodyPartLocations.at(i).y < 1) || (snakeBodyPartLocations.at(i).y > 38))
                    {
                        reset(); //Reset the grid
                    }

                    //If any of the body parts collide with the snake's head:
                    if ((i != 0) && (snakeBodyPartLocations.at(0).x == snakeBodyPartLocations.at(i).x) &&
                        (snakeBodyPartLocations.at(0).y == snakeBodyPartLocations.at(i).y))
                    {
                        reset(); //Reset the grid
                    }
                }

                //Update the board:
                for (int y = 0; y < signed(board.size()); y++) {for (int x = 0; x < signed(board.at(0).size()); ++x)
                {
                    if ((y == 0) || (y == 39) || (x == 0) || (x == 39)) {board.at(y).at(x) = 3;}
                    else {board.at(y).at(x) = 0;}
                }}
                for (int i = 0; i < signed(snakeBodyPartLocations.size()); ++i)
                {
                    board.at(snakeBodyPartLocations.at(i).y).at(snakeBodyPartLocations.at(i).x) = 1;
                }
                board.at(appleLocation.y).at(appleLocation.x) = 2;

                //Restart the clock
                snakeMoveClock.restart();
            }
        }

        void draw(sf::RenderWindow& targetWindow)
        {
            //Go through the board:
            for (int y = 0; y < signed(board.size()); y++) {for (int x = 0; x < signed(board.at(0).size()); ++x)
            {
                //If it's a drawable type:
                if ((board.at(y).at(x) == 1) || (board.at(y).at(x) == 2) || (board.at(y).at(x) == 3))
                {
                    //Create a rectangle:
                    sf::RectangleShape block;
                    block.setSize(sf::Vector2f(10, 10));
                    block.setPosition(x * 10, y * 10);

                    //Colour the rectangle accordingly:
                    if (board.at(y).at(x) == 1) {block.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);}
                    else if (board.at(y).at(x) == 2) {block.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);}
                    else if (board.at(y).at(x) == 3) {block.setFillColor(sf::Color::Black);}

                    //Draw the rectangle
                    targetWindow.draw(block);
                }
            }}
        }

        void reset()
        {
            //Generate an apple:
            while (true)
            {
                int randomAppleX = rand() % 38 + 1;
                int randomAppleY = rand() % 38 + 1;
                if (board.at(randomAppleY).at(randomAppleX) == 0)
                {
                    board.at(randomAppleY).at(randomAppleX) = 2;
                    appleLocation = sf::Vector2f(randomAppleX, randomAppleY);
                    break;
                }
            }

            //Put the snake on the board:
            snakeBodyPartLocations.clear();
            snakeBodyPartLocations.push_back(sf::Vector2f(20, 20));
            snakeDirection = down;
        }

        Snake()
        {
            //Reset the game:
            reset();
        }
};

#endif // SNAKE_HPP
```

Comment: Should I remove the [tag:SFML] tag? The `draw` function can quite easily be converted so it works with the console (but it would be very slow)

Comment: I think it's fine to leave the tag, since you make use of other sf things like vectors and clock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code would simplify greatly if you make `direction` into a class, with two private integers (valued `-1,0,1`), negation, (in)equality, and a friend operator to add `direction` to `Vector2f` (I *suppose* it is even possible to reuse `Vector2f` for that purpose). Then for example `changeDirection` test reduces to

```
        if (direction != -newDirection)
```

which is much more readable and much less error prone. The update of the head and tail positions also becomes a matter of a simple addition.